# results fetched with doctrine: a lot of unknown data into it

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, var-dump

I'm fetching an object from my database with doctrine and I would like to browse it like I would browse a php array, which should be possible.

Let me show you my entity:

```
<?php
namespace NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Account")
 */

class Account
{
    /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */

protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique = true)
 */

protected $name;  

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */

protected $code;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="parent")
 */

private  $children;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Account", inversedBy="children")
 */

private $parent;


public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->parent = new ArrayCollection();

    }

//getter & setter    

?>
```

This is created into my database and doctrine works fine

Now let's try to fetch:

```
$COA = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('NRtworksChartOfAccountsBundle:Account')->findOneById(1);

   var_dump($COA);
```

With this, I actually have the object I want. However I also have so much more things, such as Fos_UserBundle stuff which is used for my user entity (in another bundle), but is nowhere related to my entity account used here. Look at var_dump result:

```
object(NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Entity\Account)#408 (5) { ["id":protected]=> int(1) ["name":protected]=> string(5) "BILAN" ["code":protected]=> string(6) "000000" ["children":"NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Entity\Account":private]=> object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)#409 (9) { ["snapshot":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> array(0) { } ["owner":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> *RECURSION* ["association":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> array(15) { ["fieldName"]=> string(8) "children" ["mappedBy"]=> string(6) "parent" ["targetEntity"]=> string(45) "NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Entity\Account" ["cascade"]=> array(0) { } ["orphanRemoval"]=> bool(false) ["fetch"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(4) ["inversedBy"]=> NULL ["isOwningSide"]=> bool(false) ["sourceEntity"]=> string(45) "NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Entity\Account" ["isCascadeRemove"]=> bool(false) ["isCascadePersist"]=> bool(false) ["isCascadeRefresh"]=> bool(false) ["isCascadeMerge"]=> bool(false) ["isCascadeDetach"]=> bool(false) } ["em":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)#137 (10) { ["config":"Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager":private]=> object(Doctrine\ORM\Configuration)#150 (1) { ["_attributes":protected]=> array(13) { ["entityNamespaces"]=> array(3) { ["NRtworksChartOfAccountsBundle"]=> string(37) "NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Entity" ["NRtworksSubscriptionBundle"]=> string(34) "NRtworks\SubscriptionBundle\Entity" ["FOSUserBundle"]=> string(21) "FOS\UserBundle\Entity" } ["metadataCacheImpl"]=> object(Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache)#159 (3) { ["data":"Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache":private]=> array(5) { ["DoctrineNamespaceCacheKey[sf2orm_default_3f554f15ae41595a1a142aaf979fc6f613a39d4a606464e7ca2715f45fc7d314]"]=> int(1)
```

and it goes on and on until my patience is overflowed.

I tried to ladybug_dump it and it works fine, just that I can't see what's in the children or parent collection. 
In my twig I can browse it with no problem.

But I need to understand well the structure of result to re-order it.

So does someone know where all this data comes from and why it's here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "so much more things" you're seeing is related to Doctrine's [Collection](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection.php)s. These are implemented as [ArrayCollection](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php) (you instantiate them in the constructor of entities for OneToMany and ManyToMany associations), and [PersistentCollection](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php) (when an entity is fetched from the database).

Especially [PersistentCollection](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php) contains a lot of data Doctrine needs to manage it, like keeping track of what needs to be persisted towards the database when the collection changes.

I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish :(

If you're looking for a convenient way to dump your entities, have a look at [Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump()](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Util/Debug.php#L55).

If you want to use your entity as an array, you could fetch it as an array using the [getArrayResult()](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L737) method of [Doctrine\ORM\Query](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php).
Or you could have a look at the [Serializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) library by Johannes Schmitt.

**update**

The "Fos_UserBundle stuff" you're seeing is an entry `"FOSUserBundle" => "FOS\UserBundle\Entity"` in an array under `"entityNamespaces"`. This is part of the metadata within collections.

Comment: ok I was worried there was something wrong with my result.. Still I find it weird that I have FOS User Bundle into that but...

Actually the bottom of my question was how I could use my results as an array, and apparently I cannot as is. I'll try to sort it in the twig. If inefficient, I'll use one of your solutions.

Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more clear about the FosUserBundle entry.

Comment: is it possible that within the constructor I fill the array children with a doctrine query that gets all the account with this parent ? Is it proper ?

Comment: I don't understand the question :( You can't query the database for children of a row that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: if you would be so nice to have a look at my new-related question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434747/find-the-children-of-an-object-in-the-database i'm sure you could answer it
thank you